# Lease on wlan0 renews every 15 seconds

Tags: networking, wireless

Wireless performance is poor--a recent development. The following output repeats every 15 seconds in the syslog file:

```
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle dhclient: PRC: Renewing lease on wlan0.
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle dhclient: XMT: Renew on wlan0, interval 10170ms.
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle dhclient: RCV: Reply message on wlan0 from fe80::de45:17ff:fede:7f9f.
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle NetworkManager[876]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv6 state changed renew6 -> re
new6
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle NetworkManager[876]: <info>   address 2601:602:9300:6330::1/128
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle NetworkManager[876]: <info>   nameserver '2001:558:feed::1'
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle NetworkManager[876]: <info>   nameserver '2001:558:feed::2'
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle dbus[663]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispat
cher' (using servicehelper)
Jun 25 10:41:00 Bullwinkle dbus[663]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm
_dispatcher'
```

Could this be the reason for poor perfomance? Is this normal? If not, is there a fix? Apologies if this is a poorly formed question--my knowledge is weak.

Re: request for further info from Pilot6

```
root@Bullwinkle:~# lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300 [8086:4235]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1121]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi  
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1698] (rev 10)  
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0272]  
    Kernel driver in use: tg3  
root@Bullwinkle:~# cat /proc/version_signature  
Ubuntu 3.13.0-88.135-generic 3.13.11-ckt39
```

I believe I intalled Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but I don't know how to verify that.

Thanks to Rinzwind for the edit.  I hope I did better this time.
Thanks to Pilot6 for the guidance.

Comment: What is your operating system? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I think NetworkManager was being run/triggered from systemd and upstart. After

```
sudo service NetworkManager stop
```

the logs calmed down and everything seems stable.

(This was, for the record, on Linux Mint Betsy LMDE2, i.e. Debian-8-based).